# Refactoring to avoid the use of dynamic

Tags: c#

Based on the answer to my [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13629394/298754), I have ended up with the following code:

```
public class ColumnDataBuilder<T>
{
    public abstract class MyListViewColumnData
    {
        public string Name { get; protected set; }
        public int Width { get; protected set; }
        public ColumnType Type { get; protected set; }
        public delegate TOUT FormatData<out TOUT>(T dataIn);

        protected abstract dynamic GetData(T dataRow);

        public string GetDataString(T dataRow)
        {
            dynamic data = GetData(dataRow);
            switch (Type)
            {
                case ColumnType.String:
                case ColumnType.Integer:
                case ColumnType.Decimal:
                    return data.ToString();
                case ColumnType.Date:
                    return data.ToShortDateString();
                case ColumnType.Currency:
                    return data.ToString("c");
                    break;
                case ColumnType.Boolean:
                    var b = (bool)data;
                    if (b) return "Y";
                    else return "N";
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }

    }

    public class MyListViewColumnData<TOUT> : MyListViewColumnData
    {

        public MyListViewColumnData(string name, int width, ColumnType type, FormatData<TOUT> dataFormater)
        {
            DataFormatter = x => dataFormater(x); // Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/1906850/298754
            Type = type;
            Width = width;
            Name = name;
        }
        public Func<T, TOUT> DataFormatter { get; protected set; }
        protected override dynamic GetData(T dataRow)
        {
            return DataFormatter(dataRow);
        }
    }
 }
```

This is called from a factory method (in `ColumnDataBuilder`) as

```
public MyListViewColumnData Create<TOUT>(string name, int width, ColumnType type, MyListViewColumnData.FormatData<TOUT> dataFormater)
{
    return new MyListViewColumnData<TOUT>(name, width, type, dataFormater);
}
public MyListViewColumnData Create(string name, int width, MyListViewColumnData.FormatData<DateTime> dataFormater)
{
    return new MyListViewColumnData<DateTime>(name, width, ColumnType.Date, dataFormater);
}
...
```

That, in turn, is called from my code as:

```
builder.Create("Date", 40, x => x.createdDate);
```

and

```
private ListViewItem CreateListViewItem<TDATA>(IEnumerable<ColumnDataBuilder<TDATA>.MyListViewColumnData> columns, TDATA rowData)
{
    var item = new ListViewItem();
    foreach (var col in columns)
    {
        item.SubItems.Add(col.GetDataString(rowData));
    }
    item.SubItems.RemoveAt(0); // We generate an extra SubItem for some reason.
    return item;
}
```

How can I refactor this so that I'm **not** using `dynamic`, but still preserve the syntax as it currently exists in the code?

Comment: Alternatively, if this is a proper use for `dynamic`, that'd be good to know too... but I'm pretty sure it isn't.

Comment: Where does `T` come from?

Comment: Your `public abstract class MyListViewColumnData` has no generic parameters while it has `delegate TOUT FormatData<out TOUT>(T dataIn)` declared. Please make sure you post a compilable code here

Comment: @JeffVanzella - Good catch. I missed copying the class declaration.  Edited it in.

Comment: @almaz - I think this will now compile.  If it doesn't, I'll go back and post a larger block, but I am trying to keep it down to the relevant portions.

Comment: Have a look at Convert.ToString(object, IFormatProvider) and implementing your format provider. A bit more complex way, but for good separation is reasonable enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `MyListViewColumnData` class there, I would replace it with interface and move the `GetDataString` implementation to `MyListViewColumnData<TOut>`. And you don't need `dynamic` here, just use `object` instead (yes, it will use boxing for most cases except strings, but it's more efficient than dynamics).

```
public class ColumnDataBuilder<T>
{
    public interface IMyListViewColumnData
    {
        string Name { get; }
        int Width { get; }
        ColumnType Type { get; }
        string GetDataString(T dataRow);
    }

    public delegate TOut FormatData<out TOut>(T dataIn);

    public class MyListViewColumnData<TOut> : IMyListViewColumnData
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public int Width { get; private set; }
        public ColumnType Type { get; private set; }
        private readonly FormatData<TOut> _dataFormatter;

        public MyListViewColumnData(string name, int width, ColumnType type, FormatData<TOut> dataFormater)
        {
            _dataFormatter = dataFormater;
            Type = type;
            Width = width;
            Name = name;
        }
        public string GetDataString(T dataRow)
        {
            object data = _dataFormatter(dataRow);

            switch (Type)
            {
                case ColumnType.String:
                case ColumnType.Integer:
                case ColumnType.Decimal:
                    return data.ToString();
                case ColumnType.Date:
                    return ((DateTime)data).ToShortDateString();
                case ColumnType.Currency:
                    return ((decimal)data).ToString("c");
                case ColumnType.Boolean:
                    return (bool)data ? "Y" : "N";
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }

    public IMyListViewColumnData Create<TOut>(string name, int width, ColumnType type, FormatData<TOut> dataFormater)
    {
        return new MyListViewColumnData<TOut>(name, width, type, dataFormater);
    }

    public IMyListViewColumnData Create(string name, int width, FormatData<DateTime> dataFormater)
    {
        return new MyListViewColumnData<DateTime>(name, width, ColumnType.Date, dataFormater);
    }
}

public enum ColumnType
{
    String,
    Integer,
    Decimal,
    Date,
    Currency,
    Boolean
}
```

**Update**
In comments it was asked if you can extract interface for ColumnDataBuilder. Of course you can :), and the easiest way would be to use "Extract interface" refactoring from ReSharper :). If you still don't use it you'll have to do that manually (move the `IMyListViewColumnData` and `FormatData<TOut>` declarations out of `ColumnDataBuilder<T>` first):

```
public interface IColumnDataBuilder<Tin>
{
    IMyListViewColumnData Create<TOut>(string name, int width, ColumnType type, FormatData<TOut> dataFormater);
    IMyListViewColumnData Create(string name, int width, FormatData<DateTime> dataFormater);
}
```

Comment: I *knew* there had to be a better way. Thanks!

Comment: Just a followup:  Is there any way to extract an interface of `ColumnDataBuilder<>`, so that I can store it without knowing the type?  Or is that asking too much of the compiler?

Comment: @Bobson see updated answer

Comment: I'm not sure that addresses the goal, though.  I have another class (the `ListView` subclass which this is handling the data for), which could have any datatype for `Tin` there.  And I can't make it generic for other reasons, or this would be a lot simpler.  So what type do I make that property?  Or could I leave off the `<Tin>` and get this scenario working?

Comment: you should have told how you want it to work first :). If you want to write a general logic that doesn't know about specific types upfront in may be a good idea just to stop using generics... At what time ListView gets to know the type T? Where is the code that calls `ColumnDataBuilder<T>.Create` located? Does that code know about specific types? It's probably better to open a new question since we've moved quite far from original one...

Comment: Fair enough - I hadn't thought that far ahead when I asked this question.  While I was waiting for an answer, I realized I needed to separate column creation from attaching the data.  I'll see if I can formulate a new question, and then I'll link it here.

Comment: [Posted](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19270/generic-data-for-listview)